# How to restrict WordPress Admin wp-login.php on Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

How do I restrict WordPress wp-login.php using Nginx Config from accessing by the public.

I know how to restrict access using htaccess, but how can I do it on Nginx?

Here is the config I tried.

```
location /wp-login.php {
       auth_basic            "Restricted";
       auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/example.com/.htpasswd;
}
```

When I visit the wp-admin, the whole wp-login.php file can be downloaded.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue trying to block wp-login.php on my domains.

I found that if I don't match the filename exactly it will work correctly.

What ended up working for me is:

```
location ~* (wp-login)\.php$ {
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area: WordPress";
    auth_basic_user_file  /home/path/to/passwords/.htpasswd;
}
```

This setup stopped my browser from downloading the login file and actually parsing it as PHP.

Comment: Interesting. It seems this is not consistent on all Nginx setups. This actually caused my browser to download the login file whereas `^~` worked for me. Do you or anyone else know the reason for this?

Comment: This works for me, but there are cases where nginx forgets me and WordPress remembers me and allows me into pages such as /wp-admin/edit.php, showing information -- and THEN at some point nginx pops up the .htpasswd file. This leads me to believe that we should also make it work on the entire /wp-admin tree as well. I'm working on a better Regex for that.

Answer (score 4):

*This* worked for me – note `location ~*` **didn't**

```
location ^~ /wp-login.php {
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area: WordPress";
    auth_basic_user_file  /home/path/to/passwords/.htpasswd;
}
```

That's in addition to a `location /wp-admin`, of course.

I belive this is because `~*` (4th) is lower in the [Nginx search order](http://wiki.whyaskwhy.org/Nginx/Location) than `^~` (2nd).

I did wonder if the presence of a `location ~ \.php$` block in another included file was causing the wp-login block to be ignored (always worth checking your main config files) but it doesn't appear to be and reordering the file made no difference for either pattern.

Comment: another option is limiting by ip adress, but this pattern is what you will want

Answer (score 1):

You need the auth basic module:

And I think you can apply this only to directories:

```
location /wp-admin {
       auth_basic            "Restricted";
       auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/example.com/.htpasswd;
}
```

And this only works if you have apache tools instaled, if not, see this: http://wiki.nginx.org/Faq#How_do_I_generate_an_htpasswd_file_without_having_Apache_tools_installed.3F

The second point ;)

Comment: Thanks!

I tried that and yes wp-admin is protected. However, when I visit example.com/wp-login.php. The wp login screen still show.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested different snippets, but none has worked to protect both wp-admin AND wp-login.php. The problem is not with protection only; rather, it is with accessing the wp-login.php. After I entered the correct credentials as per the .htpasswd, the wp-login.php page was downloaded as an attachment. I was unable to login. This snipped did the job for me and protected both wp-admin and wp-login.php:

```
## Protect my wordpress login page and directory with a password 
    location = /wp-login.php {
    auth_basic  "Login";
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

I have written a complete answer about this. You can find it [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444298/secure-wp-login-php-in-wordpress-using-the-nginx-configuration-file/66558913#66558913).