# Secure wp-login.php in wordpress using the nginx configuration file

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx

I want to block URL access to wp-admin and wp-login.php using Nginx webserver. To achieve this, I have edited the WordPress VirtualHost file that is located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com` because I have Nginx Server Blocks in place where I host multiple domains and I added the below code to deny all Nginx config directives inside that server block (i.e., domain) except for my IP:

```
  location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
                allow 111.111.111.111;
                deny all;
  }
```

What I get is this:

1. Anyone can access https://example.com/wp-login.php
2. Everyone (including me) gets a 403 Forbidden error when they try to access https://example.com/wp-admin/
   Required: How can we configure this properly so that I only can access it?

Answer (score 2):

I have finally solved the myth of this question, and I did it differently. Instead of relying on the IP to set access permissions to the wp-login.php page, I have configured a Password Authentication with Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04. I have created the password file using the apache utilities. Follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install it. After you install it, open the Nginx configuration file that is linked to your WordPress site: 
 `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` 
or this configuration file, if you use blocks:
`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` 

Add this snippet:

```
## Protect my wordpress login page and directory with a password 
    location = /wp-login.php {
    auth_basic  "Login";
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Please note that `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;` must match your current PHP version which you are running on your website. The above snippet worked for me to protect wp-admin AND wp-login.php. I struggled to come up with this because all other versions used to download the login page as a file or to protect the wp-admin directory without the wp-login.php

Please don't hesitate to add more to this topic to refine it.

Answer (score 1):

You can secure any URL with nginx by doing the following steps:

1. Setup a secret URL and set a secret cookie when users access this URL
2. Verify the secret cookie for all requests to the URL you want to protect, reject if cookie is not matched.

Let's take WordPress, in this case the URL I want to hide is the admin. The below is a working example, don't forget to change the secret token and secret url to your own ones.

```
    set $admin_token "generate-token-with-uuidgen";
     
    # Access this url to get admin_token cookie.
    # You must change this url to a secret url only you know
    location = /secret-url-change-me {
        add_header Set-Cookie "admin_token=$admin_token; Path=/";
        return 302 "/wp-login.php";  # redirect to the real url
    }
    
    # Verify cookie for the url you want to protect.
    location /wp-login.php {
        if ($cookie_admin_token != $admin_token) {
            return 403;
        }
        try_files $uri @wordpress;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @wordpress;
    }

    # Here is the real location of wordpress
    # can be proxy, php-fpm, etc
    location @wordpress{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6000;
    }
```

Now if a user access http://example.org/wp-login.php directly, they will get 403 error. They has to access http://example.org/secret-url-change-me to get the secret cookie first to open http://example.org/wp-login.php